# rails routes question - how to take all parameters to end of URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In the rails config/routes.rb file, how do I ensure that the first route here takes all characters after the initial /site and uses this for this route (assigning it to :path).

```
  map.connect 'sites/:path', :controller => 'xxx', :action => 'yyy'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

In other words how to avoid any URL that goes http://mysite/sites/, to be missed by the first route and then picked up by the second route?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the second route first or..

use [Route Globbing (Section 4.9)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?